# shape 3D numpy array python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create 3D array with a dimension which depends on the length of a 2D list

Method 1 :
the length of list_1 is 2 and each element has the same length

```
list_1 = [[1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5]]
array_1 = np.zeros((2,len(list_1), 114))
```

the shape of array_1 is  (2,2,114)

method 2 :

the length of list_2 is also 2 but elements do not have the same length

```
list_2 = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4]]
array_2 = [np.zeros((len(list_2[i]),114)) for i in range(len(list_2))]    
array_2 = np.array(list_2, dtype=object)
```

In this case the shape of array_2 is (2,)

Does someone know the reason ? I do not understand why I do not get the same shape.

Is there a way to get the same shape ?

Comment: What's the expected outcome? You're basically trying to create a matrix with rows of different length. Does that make sense?

Comment: The first shape is the expected outcome. For my script I need to use matrix which do not have the same number of rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a list of 2 arrays, that differ in the number of rows:

```
In [130]: [np.zeros((len(list_2[i]), 3)) for i in range(len(list_2))]
Out[130]: 
[array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]]),
 array([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]])]
```

`np.array` cannot combine those into one 3d array, so it makes a shape 2 array, containing those same 2 arrays:

```
In [131]: np.array(_, object)
Out[131]: 
array([array([[0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0.]]), 
       array([[0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0.]
              [0., 0., 0.],
              [0., 0., 0.]])], dtype=object)
```

If you don't include the `object` dtype it warns about making a "ragged array".

Using `len(list_1)` for the first case, and `len(list_2[i])` in the second, are two very different situations.  In one you are using length of the list itself, and the the length of the sublists.

If you truncated the sublists to the same length:

```
In [137]: np.array([np.zeros((len(list_2[i][:4]),114)) for i in range(len(list_2))],object).shape
Out[137]: (2, 4, 114)
```

The subarrays now have the same shape (4,114), and can be combined into one 3d array.